# How to disable composite keys on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, text-input

I've got my mac two months ago and there is a problem that kinda bugs me to death. It is related to input languages and composite characters (those made up from more than one character, for example in Bulgarian Phonetic layout, the characters 'a(cyrillic a) produce ђ ).

I'm looking for a way to disable this behavior as I almost never (let's say never had to use them) and it gets in the way when I need to type ' followed by some other character - for example when I try to write python comments and I'm in Bulgarian Phonetic, when i type 3 ''' and then press enter for next line, a fourth ' is added and I have to delete it and press enter again.

Any ideas on how to disable this behavior. I couldn't find anything on the interwebs, but I believe it's because I can't formulate my search query right, as I don't even know how this feature is called.

Comment: Zdravei, try using Keyboard Layout editor like [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

Comment: FYI if it helps, it appears that the Bulgarian keyboard layout uses ` for the dead key instead of the single quote Bulgarian - Phonetic uses.

Comment: @ghoppe - it could, but I am not at all used to Bulgarian standard layout, just the Bulgarian phonetic. Thanks though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to similar questions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455799/276656) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/191424/33654) **[Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/)** is the tool to edit and eliminate *dead keys*.

Comment: I was hoping there was another way :) Well it seems that I would be making a new layout. Thanks!

Comment: You can download a ready-made layout for German keyboards from https://github.com/sebroeder/osx-keyboard-layout-german-no-deadkeys

Comment: I've created [a `US` keymap with dead keys removed](https://github.com/iandunn/dotfiles/blob/ed0b81f0dfdb17c34d881ff57a78f4a264c91886/keyboards/US%20No%20Dead%20Keys/readme.md) if that's useful to anyone. That would let you skip Ukelele and just install the new layout directly.

Answer (score 16):

Composite keys are bound to the 'Input Source' of your mac.

In your 'System Preferences', in 'Language & Text' you will see the option 'Input Source'.

If you have selected 'U.S. International - PC' for example, you will have the dead key problem. But if you change that to ordinary 'U.S.' you are fine and dead keys won't be a problem any longer.

Comment: The standard U.S. layout has a few dead keys under option as well. And most European layouts don't have (pre-installed) alternative versions that wouldn't have as many dead keys.

Comment: I can confirm that dead keys persist on every English QWERTY layout